# How can I make a command available inside another command's argument?

Tags: macros, environments

When I define an environment with `\newenvironment`, I can use `newcommand` inside the "before" part, to make commands available to the code inside the environment.

Is this possible with simple commands? In other words, can I make a command such that into the argument the user can use a macro that is not defined outside?

Example: suppose I want to code a command `\set` to typeset mathematical sets definitions and I want a `\suchthat` command to be used inside, as in:

```
\set{x\in X \suchthat x > 42}
```

This is easy, but I'd like the `\suchthat` command to only be available inside an argument of `\set`.

Comment: Yes you can do this.

Comment: If it was a funny way to say that I should edit the title to "How can I" instead of only "Can I", then thanks, I'll edit the title :P

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can define a command as

```
\newcommand\set[1]{%%
   \begingroup
     \def\suchthat{... some definition...}%%
     ... other macro content ....
    \endgroup}
```

And this will make `\suchthat` available inside the macro.

You could have done this with `\bgroup` and `\egroup`, but that creates a subformula with consequences on how the spacing is handling if used in math mode. 
The `\begingroup` and `\endgroup` here localize the definition of new macros.  You can use any of the following to define a local command, `\def`, `\edef`, and `\newcommand`.

Following the suggestion of @barbarabeeto you could do something like this in your preamble:

```
\makeatletter
\def\ae@suchthat{... definition of such that ...}
\newcommand\aset[1]{%%
  \let\suchthat\ae@suchthat
    the body of the macro: #1
  \let\suchthat\undefined
}
\makeatother
```

This is much better.  In addition to the reasons that barbarabeeto suggests, this would also allow your macro---should you so wish---to define or set values that you may want to access later in the document.  With the `\begingroup/\endgroup` approach, those would have to be globalized, which might not be what you'd want.

A hybrid approach could look like

```
\makeatletter
\def\ae@suchthat{... definition of such that ...}
\newcommand\aset[1]{%%
  \begingroup
    \let\suchthat\ae@suchthat
      the body of the macro: #1
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother
```

Comment: Thanks! Can I use `\newcommand` instead of `\def` inside `\bgroup`?

Comment: this will result in repeated definitions of `\suchthat` -- once every time `\set` is used.  it would be better to make two definitions at "base" level: `\suchthata{... real definition ...}` and `\suchthatb{}`, and then within `\set`, at the beginning `\let\suchthat\suchthata` and at the end disable it with `\let\suchthat\suchthatb`.  this doesn't make `\suchthat` invalid, so it would probably be better to define `\suchthatb` to produce an error or at least a warning message.

Comment: @barbarabeeton `\suchthatb{}` can be `\undefined`

Comment: @barbarabeeton Updated answer to reflect your suggestion.  Thank you.

Comment: I'd go with the first suggestion with grouping together with `\let`, so no “undefine” is necessary; however, `\begingroup` and `\endgroup` are *necessary* here, because `\bgroup` and `\egroup` will make a subformula if used in math mode, with nefarious consequences with regard to spacing: the spaces in the subformula are frozen.

Answer (score 6):

A. Ellett's suggestions are good, but there are some subtleties connected with this approach.

1. Localizing the definition with `\bgroup` and `\egroup` is bad, because the `\set` macro is clearly used in math mode. Such a construction would make a subformula, with the consequence that spaces are frozen and don't participate with stretching and shrinking on the line; using `\begingroup` and `\endgroup` doesn't suffer from this problem.
2. A default definition of `\suchthat` must be given anyway, because you can happen to want `\suchthat` in a section title.
3. Both commands should be made robust, for the same reason.

Here's an implementation.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\newrobustcmd{\suchthat}{%
  \@latex@error{Use \noexpand\suchthat only in \string\set}
    {You are allowed to use \noexpand\suchthat only in the\MessageBreak
     argument of \string\set}%
}
\newcommand\giga@suchthat{\mid}
\newrobustcmd{\set}[1]{%
  \begingroup
  \let\suchthat\giga@suchthat
  \{\,#1\,\}%
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{The set $\set{x\in X \suchthat x>42}$}

Let's study $\set{x\in X \suchthat x>42}$.

\suchthat

\end{document}
```

The output in the terminal:

```
! LaTeX Error: Use \suchthat only in \set.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.27 \suchthat

? h
You are allowed to use \suchthat only in the
argument of \set
```

The output

[image]